# Is ruby quiz still alive?

Tags: ruby

A google search brings up 3 retired versions: www.rubyquiz.com (v1), http://www.splatbang.com/rubyquiz/ (v2), http://rubyquiz.strd6.com/ (v3). It looks like that last quiz posted to v3 was in 2010.

Is there a Ruby Quiz 4 or something like it?

Comment: Not a programming question. Off topic.

Comment: I tried asking this on Programmers, and it got closed there as well.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: That site was mentioned in the question, and he noted that it was retired.